# Bootstrap.css not getting added to index.html in dist

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I have a grunt task configured (I am working existing project). I am not sure where to find particular task. I have an "index.html" file getting created and added to the "dist" folder after every compile and build. But in the index.html i manually have to add the following every time:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

and also the -

```
    <base href="/">
```

For AJS.

What might be the possible issue?

I don't want to edit bower.json instead do it using grunt task. so how do i do it?

I have the following:

var buildConfig = module.exports = {

```
    // Wiredep options
     wiredepOptions: {

    //
    // devDependencies: true, // <-- injects bower devDependencies
    //
    // exclude: [             // <-- List of patterns to exclude
    //     
    //     /bootstrap\.js/
    // ]

    "overrides": {
      "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
          "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
           ]
      }
},
```

This gives me error. how do i resolve it?

Comment: We'd have to see your gruntfile, or atleast the part where you inject your css

Comment: I am new to grunt and this is an existing project., So where can i usually find that css injection?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [`main`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json#L17) object in Bootstrap's bower.json mention a reference to the `less` file not the `css`

```
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

[Wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) is the grunt task that is responsible for injecting those assets so it have no idea where the CSS file is. You can do it by providing an override in `wiredep` task in your gruntfile.js as follow:

```
wiredep: {
    ...,
    overrides: {
      'bootstrap': {
        'main': [
          'dist/js/bootstrap.js',
          'dist/css/bootstrap.css'    // Note this
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Running `grunt wiredep` again will inject the CSS file to your HTML as expected.

**Note:** This won't work unless your HTML have this HTML comment

```
<!-- bower:css -->
  The styles will be injected here
<!-- endbower -->
```

Comment: But., i have only - bootstrap.css.map in my dist and i already have - maps: {
                ...,
                src: ['bower_components/**/*.css.map'],
                dest: 'dist/client/assets'
            } in my gruntfile.js

Comment: Examine your bootstrap dist directory and search for the CSS file. There are minified and unminified version.

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve it with editing Gruntfile but added this in bower.json :

```
  "overrides": {
  "bootstrap": {
     "main": [
       "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ]
     }
```